# wp remote post getting a 404 error code

Tags: marketing-cloud, php, wordpress

```
$info = array(
  'values' => array(
'email' => 'email@email.com',
'firstname' => "firstname",
'lastname' => "lastname",
'source' => "WEB",
  ),
);
$infoo=json_encode($info);
$sf_auth = 'Bearer ' . $data['accessToken'];

$finalUrl="https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/dataevents/key:Web_Registrations/rows/GUID:7777";
$result= wp_remote_post( $finalUrl, array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'timeout' => 45,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking' => true,
    'headers' => array(
       'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
       'Authorization' => $sf_auth,
      ),
   'body' => $infoo,
   'cookies' => array()
    )
 );
```

Trying to post it within wordpress but i am receiving message: Not Found and errorcode: 404

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?? Thank you

Comment: Have you filled out the External Key field in your Data Extension, within Marketing Cloud? This is per default set to a GUID value. You want to change it to Web_Registrations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the replies. I solved it by changing the method to PUT & httpversion to 1.1

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to change the method from `POST` to `PUT`? (Vide: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/putDataExtensionRowByKey.htm )

Additionally make sure that External Key of that data extension is for sure **Web_Registrations** and primary key of that Data Extension is for sure **GUID**.